# What's the best way to deal with the market swings?

Tags: investing, investment-strategies

So I've been trading for a while.  Having said that, the current bear markets are driving me to get some "deals".  I think I bought some investments for a decent price. Having said that, I can't go back to forgetting about them.  I, now, watch the market move up and down.  When it spikes up or down - I'm torn.  I acted on a big change - sold at a loss, then bought back high - sighs.  How can I stop myself from looking?

Comment: Spread betting or Share dealing may I ask? The latter, you know from confidence the longer term will prosper. The former, larger the bankroll to withstand the swings and 'turbulence'

Comment: Trade with a written plan, don't place trades during the day based on your emotions, place your conditional orders after market close only. Only trade if a stock starts moving up and only sell if a stock starts moving down (using stop loss orders).

Comment: Assuming you'd made a calculated decision in choosing which stock to buy, and therefore have some amount of long-term confidence in your decision, why wouldn't seeing a drop in value trigger a "buy more" re-action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your daily routine so that you do not look at the market.  Since this is rather hard to do, at first you should just spend sometime everyday noting: where, when, and how you were looking at the market.  After just watching yourself for a bit (a few weeks or more) then figure out what else you could do instead.  This "else" will have to be as "enjoyable" as watching the market.

Comment: [Browsing the `habit` tag at Personal Productivity.SE may be helpful.](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habit?sort=votes&pageSize=50)